# What's the Promise equivalent of CompositeFuture in Vert.x 3.8.1+?

Tags: promise, future, vert.x

I have a Vert.x 3.7.1 method that deploys a bunch of verticles and if all of the deployments succeed, sends a message through the event bus that does some startup work. The structure of the method looks like this:

```
void deploy() {
   Future<Void> v1Future = Future.future();
   Future<Void> v2Future = Future.future();
   // ...

vertx.deployVerticle(new SomeVerticle(), result -> {
   if (result.succeeded()) {
     v1Future.complete();
   } else {
     v1Future.fail(result.cause());
    }
});

// ...

List<Future<Void>> allFutures = ImmutableList.of(v1Future, v2Future);
CompositeFuture.all(allFutures).setHandler(result -> {
   if (result.succeeded()) {
     vertx.eventBus().send("some-address");
   }
});
}
```

I want to replicate this same functionality with `Promise`s in Vert.x 3.8.1+, since `Future.future()` and most of the associated methods are now deprecated. The problem is, there's no `CompositePromise` or anything that seems similar to `Future`s. How can I execute a series of deployments and then if and only if all deployments succeed, do something else using the new `Promise` class in Vert.x 3.8.1+?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CompositeFuture` still exists and it will not be replaced. The reason is that what needs to be composed are the asynchronous *results*, not the promises.

Here is how you can compose the futures corresponding to each promise:

```
void deploy() {
  Promise<Void> v1Promise = Promise.promise();
  Promise<Void> v2Promise = Promise.promise();
  // ...

  vertx.deployVerticle(new SomeVerticle(), result -> {
    if (result.succeeded()) {
      v1Promise.complete();
    } else {
      v1Promise.fail(result.cause());
    }
  });

  // ...

  List<Future> allFutures = ImmutableList.of(v1Promise.future(), v2Promise.future());
  CompositeFuture.all(allFutures).setHandler(result -> {
    if (result.succeeded()) {
      vertx.eventBus().send("some-address", message);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: is it possible to use `vertx.deployVerticle(new SomeVerticle(), v1Promise)`? It would be nice for fluency

Comment: Sure, if you change v1Promise type to `Promise<String>`. I kept the original code here to focus on the question asked.

Comment: This might be more obvious with Vert.x 4 (currently in milestones) that provides methods returning `Future` as well, so the example above looks more streamlined.